# Problem using static variable in a static function

Tags: c++

i have a full static class, using a std::map

thats the simplified case

**.h**

```
#ifndef KEYBOARD_H
#define KEYBOARD_H

#include <map>

class Keyboad {

    static std::map<char, bool> pressed;    

    static void keyPressedEvent(char _key); 

};

#endif
```

**.cpp**

```
#include "Keyboard.h"

void Keyboard :: keyPressedEvent(char _key) {

    Keyboard :: pressed[_key] = true;

}
```

but there is a problem with the static member variable, because i get

```
Undefined symbols:
"Keyboard::pressed", referenced from:
__ZN15Keyboard7pressedE$non_lazy_ptr in Keyboard.o
(maybe you meant: __ZN15Keyboard7pressedE$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

when i remove it, it runs ok

why do i get this problem, there should be no problem when using a static variable :/

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to define the `pressed` map in your .cpp file:

```
#include "Keyboard.h"
std::map<char, bool> Keyboard::pressed;

// The rest as before
```

Comment: but why, when its already declared in class Keyboad which i include?

Comment: @Peter, it is declared in your class, but not *defined*.

Comment: @Peter: Think of the header file as a *description* of what your class "includes" (this is called *declaration*). It is enough to let you compile the code, but to link it into an executable you also need to "produce the actual goods". That's what the extra line above does (this is called *definition*).

Comment: ok, but when i want to use the class somewhere else, i dont need to declare it (i just call Keyboard::foo), because its static functions and (members? and now iam confused) get defined automaticly

Answer (score 6):

You should add this to .cpp file

```
std::map<char, bool> Keyboad::pressed;
```

Consider static class members as global variables. Compiler should allocate memory for them inside of the only object file. So you should define them in corresponding source file.

Answer (score 2):

A static member in the class definition is just a declaration.  You
still have to provide the definition, exactly like you did for the
function.  Just add

```
std::map<char, bool> Keyboard::pressed;
```

in a source file somewhere.  (For mapping `char`s, you might also
consider a simple

```
bool Keyboard::pressed[256];
```

, indexed with the `char` converted to `unsigned char`.)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a simpler case. A global variable `counter` is declared in **multiple** header files:

```
int counter; // This appears in 3 HEADER files.
```

Few source files do refer it. When you compile and link it, compiler would emit linker error saying that `counter` is already defined in some set of .OBJ files (Error message is dependent on compiler).

To solve this, you just put `extern` in front of variable (in **all** header files):

```
extern int counter; // This appears in 3 HEADER files.
```

And when you rebuild it, linker will complain that `counter` is not defined anywhere.

To solve this issue, you **define** this variable in **one** source file (any one):

```
int counter;
```

And it resolves the issue.

The static-variable of class is nothing but a global variable, which can be accessed by `classname::variablename` format. The accessibility is same - global.